# Generic promise with parameter in Typescript not working

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, tsx

I am trying implement something like data-table in tsx.

Well, I have some piece of code

```
type Props<T> {
  query:() => Promise<{data:T[]; count:number}>
  columns:T[]
}

type Column<T> { 
  field: keyof T
}
```

Then I have simple component:

```
<CustomTable columns=[{field:"id"},{field:"name"}] query={async () => {
  await ... (fetching data)
}} />
```

This is works correctly (autocompletion on field props works, no tsc error etc...)

Problems start when I try add some parameter to promise define, for example:

```
type Props<T> {
  query:(pageSize:number) => Promise<{data:T[]; count:number}>
  columns:T[]
}
```

and component

```
 <CustomTable columns=[{field:"id"},{field:"name"}] query={async pageSize => {
  await ... (fetching data with pageSize param) 
}} />
```

This is produce typescript error: ``type of property 'data' are incompatible`

Fun fact, when I specify type explicit:

```
 <CustomTable columns=[{field:"id"},{field:"name"}] query={async (pageSize:number) => {
  await ... (fetching data with pageSize param) 
}} />
```

all works as expected.
So my question, what is correct typescript definition?

Thanks

EDIT: Playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-2lnpol?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, *as plain text in the body of your post*. Ideally I could paste such code into a standalone IDE and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values. (If you want to provide a [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mbBldm) that's great, but please also put the full example *in the body of the post as text*.)

Comment: Ah forgot, sorry. Here is react playground:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-2lnpol?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: Was my comment too wordy?  I tried to stress that a [mre] should be **plain text in the body of the post**, suitable for pasting as-is into a single file in an IDE.  But somehow I always just get external links when I say that.  How can I reach people better with my comments?